# 18.04 Xubuntu Not Waking

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, wakeup, canonical-livepatch

I have a recent issue with Xubuntu 18.04 not always waking.  It seems to be just the in the  morning.  I pulled the syslog and see some failures like "Failed to start snap.canonical-livepatch".  Could that be it?  Are there any suggestions on how to resolve this waking issue? I don't see a way to attach a file so pasted part of syslog below but the line formatting gets lost.  A hard reboot was done at 6:29 to recover.

```
Aug  2 00:13:43 Pavilion anacron[10964]: Job `cron.weekly' started
Aug  2 00:13:43 Pavilion anacron[11320]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2021-08-02
Aug  2 00:13:46 Pavilion anacron[10964]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Aug  2 00:17:02 Pavilion CRON[11354]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  2 00:18:43 Pavilion anacron[10964]: Job `cron.monthly' started
Aug  2 00:18:43 Pavilion anacron[10964]: Job `cron.monthly' terminated
Aug  2 00:18:43 Pavilion anacron[10964]: Normal exit (3 jobs run)
Aug  2 00:18:43 Pavilion anacron[11367]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.monthly' to 2021-08-02
Aug  2 00:24:05 Pavilion canonical-livepatch[983]: Checking with livepatch service.
Aug  2 00:24:06 Pavilion canonical-livepatch[983]: Updated last-check.
Aug  2 00:24:06 Pavilion canonical-livepatch[983]: No updates available at this time.
Aug  2 00:24:06 Pavilion canonical-livepatch[983]: No payload available.
Aug  2 00:24:06 Pavilion canonical-livepatch[983]: client information is recent, not refreshing
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.b68a9a6c-90b7-4547-ac77-1b2aabd68605.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion kernel: [40663.261413] audit: type=1400 audit(1627889048.755:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/11420/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=11394 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.b68a9a6c-90b7-4547-ac77-1b2aabd68605.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: Failed to start snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.b68a9a6c-90b7-4547-ac77-1b2aabd68605.scope.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.8bf1748a-2d29-451a-a4b3-7d3e10bf4dc9.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.8bf1748a-2d29-451a-a4b3-7d3e10bf4dc9.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: Failed to start snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.8bf1748a-2d29-451a-a4b3-7d3e10bf4dc9.scope.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion kernel: [40663.371629] audit: type=1400 audit(1627889048.863:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/11420/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=11422 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.c33ea6d0-0f7b-4e28-80ea-1e898d4261a5.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.c33ea6d0-0f7b-4e28-80ea-1e898d4261a5.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion systemd[2615]: Failed to start snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.c33ea6d0-0f7b-4e28-80ea-1e898d4261a5.scope.
Aug  2 00:24:08 Pavilion kernel: [40663.451634] audit: type=1400 audit(1627889048.943:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/11420/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=11447 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  2 00:24:09 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.957a2768-0ade-418b-b5cb-6aff2d686c08.scope: Failed to add PIDs to scope's control group: Permission denied
Aug  2 00:24:09 Pavilion systemd[2615]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.957a2768-0ade-418b-b5cb-6aff2d686c08.scope: Failed with result 'resources'.
Aug  2 00:24:09 Pavilion systemd[2615]: Failed to start snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.957a2768-0ade-418b-b5cb-6aff2d686c08.scope.
Aug  2 00:24:09 Pavilion kernel: [40663.533609] audit: type=1400 audit(1627889049.027:113): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="/snap/core/11420/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0" pid=11472 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x60f, date = 2010-09-29
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.15.0-151-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-042) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #157-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 23:07:57 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 4.15.0-151.157-generic 4.15.18)
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-151-generic root=UUID=27c52f02-9597-42b3-b1f3-d2aa0c2ce927 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009afff] usable
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009b000-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e4000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000cf69ffff] usable
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cf6a0000-0x00000000cf6adfff] ACPI data
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cf6ae000-0x00000000cf6dffff] ACPI NVS
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000cf6e0000-0x00000000cf6fffff] reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion mtp-probe: checking bus 8, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb8/8-1"
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fff00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001afffffff] usable
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 2.5 present.
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: HP-Pavilion NC715AAR-ABA a6712f/Benicia, BIOS 5.39    05/06/2009
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion kernel: [    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Aug  2 06:29:50 Pavilion systemd-modules-load[269]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

Comment: Livepatch not starting is not going to be related to 'waking'.  It's possible your system is actually going into a full hiberate mode instead of a standby mode, and that could prevent easy waking.  When you say "not waking" can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: This might be a long shot, but do you have a `QCA6174` wireless adapter? See `lspci`.

Comment: By not waking, I mean that I wiggle the mouse and hit all of the keys but the screen stays black.  I also hear no hard drive activity.

Comment: I'm not sure which is my wireless.   02)
01:00.0 Communication controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. HSF 56k Data/Fax Modem
01:05.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller (rev 70)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful to anyone but here goes.  Eventually my system would not boot.  None of the recover functions available prior to boot would work either.
I had a CD of Lubuntu 18.04 LTS i386/ and when loading that at startup it offered several recovery methods that also did not work but one did show that an fsck was needed on /dev/sda1.  I then loaded a live version of ubuntu and ran sudo umount /dev/sda1 followed by sudo fsck /dev/sda1.  This found several errors and was able to correct.  I rebooted and the system was working again.